# Conditional probability update for correlated Poisson variables

Tags: probability, correlation, poisson-distribution

Some background:

I am trying to estimate the number of failures in two related machine populations. I model machine failures in a year as a correlated Poisson process as such:

$Y_0,\ Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are three independent Poisson processes with arrival rates:
$\lambda_0$, $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.

$X_1$ and $ X_2$ are the number of machine failures seen in the two populations respectively. These discrete stochastic variables are defined as such:

$$X_1= Y_0+Y_1$$

$$X_2= Y_0+Y_2$$

$X_1$ and $X_2$ thus have the following correlation:

$$\rho = \frac{ \lambda_0}{\sqrt{( \lambda_0+\lambda_1)( \lambda_0+\lambda_2)}}$$

The joint probability function is:
$$P[X_1=i,X_2=j]=e^{-(\lambda_0+\lambda_1+\lambda_2)}\sum_{k=0}^{i\wedge j}\frac{\lambda_0^k}{k!}\frac{\lambda_1^{(i-k)}}{(i-k)!}\frac{\lambda_2^{(j-k)}}{(j-k)!}$$

I have fitted this bi-variate distribution to empirical data for several years and it does a good job in fitting to observed machine failures.

Question:

I am told of machine failures in both populations at the end of each month in the year. Lets call the running total of these failures $a$ and $b$ for $X_1$ and $X_2$ respectively. In addition I know what fraction of year is left. Lets call this $t$.

How should I calculate the probability of end of year machine failure counts given this information?

$$P[X_1=i|\ a,X_2=j|\ b, t]$$

Assume that $\lambda_0$, $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ remain stable. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Note that (a) you have three total parameters, (b) you are using only two pieces of data (i.e., statistics) and (c) you state you have per-month totals as well (but aren't using them). So, you're throwing some potentially valuable information away since two statistics won't be sufficient for three parameters. Imagine, for example, that there are no failures in a given month for one population, but there are some in the other. This immediately gives you additional information about the rates that the running totals won't.

Comment: Regarding $(a)$ and $(b)$ if we assumed $X_1$ to be an independent processes with yearly arrival rate of $\lambda_1$ then $P[X_1=i|a, t]$ is simply $0$ if $i<a$ or $e^{-t\lambda_1}(\frac{(t\lambda_1)^{i-a}}{(i-a)!})$ for $i>=a$. My question really is how do I generalize this to the correlated bivarite case? For $(c)$ I understand that I may be throwing some valuable information away but I think knowing the conditional probabilities at the end of each month using a simple analytic formula for EOY machine failure counts will help me a lot.